# How to characterize the kernels of pure states on a $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, characters

If $A$ is a *commutative* $C^*$ $*$-algebra, then the kernel of a nontrivial character is a maximal ideal.

> If $A$ is an arbitrary $C^*$-algebra, what kind of subspace is the kernel of a [pure state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(functional_analysis)#Pure_states)?

The motivation is the following: in the commutative case, we have [the $C^*$-algebra version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_C*-algebra_version), in which the concept of "character" (or, equivalently: maximal ideal) is central; if the algebra is no longer commutative, the space of characters (the spectrum of the algebra) is replaced by the pure state space. I would therefore like to understand what the correspondence between characters and maximal ideals changes into when the underlying algebra is no longer commutative.

Comment: The set of pure states is in bijection with the set of all modular maximal left ideals of $A$. This is not an exact answer to the question you ask, but I thought it might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

With the following two posts:

[$\tau$ is a pure state and $\tau(a)=0$. Then $a=b+c$ for some $b,c$ with $\tau (b^*b)=\tau(cc^*)=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066168)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223588

I believe you can conclude a state is pure iff its kernel is equal to $I+I*$ where $I$ is a left ideal. The first direction is obvious. To show the converse, according to the second post, we have that $I$ is the kernel of a state and hence, by the first post, we know that state is pure.